# Assistance with inheritance issue in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a 2 C++ classes(A and B), let's say B inherits from A.

They both need to have a toString() function. They are being called from a function that returns the base class type. After returning, I want to call the tostring() function for the correct type of class. If the function returns a B type object, I want to call the toString() from the B class.

I think my problem is coming from the fact that the function returns a reference to the base class so it is calling the function from the base class.

Example classes:

```
class A
{
  std::string toString();
};

class B
 : public A
{
  int extraThingToPrint;
  std::string toString(); //prints a different message than the A version
};
```

Example function:

```
A otherClass::scan()
{

   if(otherVar == 'a') return A();
   else if(otherVar == 'bb') return B();
}

std::cout << scan().toString(); //if bb plz print B.toString() and not A.toString() (but if a, use A.toString())
```

Comment: `toString` in your example is not `virtual`, so inheritance does not come into play. Your `B::toString` shadows `A::toString`.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if in my code both A's and B's were virtual or if just A's was virtual? I believe I have tried both ways with no difference.

Comment: That's because, even though it looks as if `scan` is returning an instance of `B`, it's actually not. An instance of `B` is created and the `A`-part of that is copied onto a new instance of `A`. Inheritance only works if you use references or pointers.

Comment: you should post an [mcve].

Comment: Kudos to @MicroVirus . I was able to get it working by changing the return type to a pointer of the base class.

`A* Other::testPrint()
{
 myInt = 25;
 if (myInt==25)
 {
  return new B();
 }
 else
 {
  return new A();
 }
}`

`int main()
{
 Other other;
 other.testPrint()->toString();
}`

First post here, so apologies for formatting issues...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`otherClass::scan()` returns `A` by value. When you are trying to return `B()`, it causes slicing, and only `A` part is returned. True type of returned object is `A`, no matter what you will write inside your function.

You need to return either reference or [smart] pointer for dynamic dispatch to work.

Comment: Or more specific: It causes the (default) `operator=(const A&)` of class `A` to be invoked on a (fresh) instance of `A` with the (newly created) `B()` as parameter. And that operator only copies the fields from `A`.

Comment: @dhke yes. If we'll be lucky, this behavior will be disabled in C++17.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot It wouldn't matter here. An `A` is an `A`. It doesn't matter what gets copied.

Comment: @juanchopanza slicing is surprising for many and sometimes accidental. Today it yields only a warning sometimes. If proposal will come, this will lead to compile-time error.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Well, that just leaves me with about 9,999 other features I'd like to have cleaned up in that particular language ;-).

Comment: The point is that the problem isn't about fields getting copied. It is about types.

Comment: @juanchopanza The problem is really about me being too used to coding in Java haha. We had example code in Java for a lexical analyzer which does things similar to the way I described above. I guess Java is smart enough to know what class it is supposed to be using?

Comment: @TomD. In java you do not deal with values. You deal with references (which are passed by value). This causes another deal of problems (like `operator=` and method `.assign` behaving differently if you apply them to original reference, or passed to function). Got me several times when refactoring.

Comment: @TomD. It isn't about being smart enough. Java and C++ are different. You need to understand the semantics of the code you write.

Answer (score 0):

First `toString` needs to be virtual in your base class, then you need to return a reference(or a pointer) to the base class type that points to either the base class or derived class object. Something like this:

```
   class A
   {
      virtual std::string toString();
   };

   A* otherClass::scan()
   {
     A* ret;
     if(otherVar == 'a') 
          ret=new A();
     else if(otherVar == 'bb');
          ret=new B();

     return ret;
   }

    A* ret=scan();
    std::cout << ret->toString();

    delete ret;//delete once you are done
```

Comment: better use e.g. `std::unique_ptr`; the `new` and raw pointer teaches bad habits